# Upload Photos Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

I need to upload images using selenium.

I'm trying to use the input (attached image) with the `sendkeys` command, but with no success.

[image]

```
foto = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@accept='image/*,image/heif,image/heic']")
        sleep(5)
        foto.click()
        sleep(5)
        foto.send_keys("C:\image11.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading file with Selenium is done by sending the uploaded file to a special element. This is not an element you are clicking as a user via GUI to upload elements. The element actually receiving uploaded files normally matching this XPath:
`//input[@type='file']`
Again, this element is not visible to a user.
Try uploading your file with this code:

```py
find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']").send_keys("C:\image11.jpg")
```

**UPD**
The code I gave you works.
This is the fully working code - I tried this on my PC with my FB account uploading some document. I've erased the screenshot details for privacy reasons, but it clearly worked

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
)

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.facebook.com/"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='email']"))).send_keys(my_username)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='pass']"))).send_keys(my_password)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='login']"))).click()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/create/item")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"))).send_keys("C:/Users/my_user/Downloads/doch.jpeg")
```

This is the screenshot of what this code does:
[image]

Comment: I understand what you said, so it's impossible to identify the input, because it's not visible?

your code suggestion did not work, could not find the input

Comment: If that element exists you can find it with dev tools

Comment: can you share a link to that page so we can debug?

Comment: is the FaceBook marketplace

Comment: please share a link

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/create/item

Comment: Error:

File "c:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Web\VS\FaceBook\analise2.py", line 32
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"))).send_keys("C:\Users\felip\Downloads\download.png")
                                                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Change slashes. See my code..

Comment: For some reason it didn't work the element was not found.

The system stops working and the page closes

Comment: Clean all the cookies. Open facebook, open devtools -> application - > clean all the cookies, casches etc. I had the same issue while working on your code

Comment: sorry, where do I find these cookies for cleaning?

Comment: As I wrote: dev tools -> application tab. maybe see some tutorials for that. Anyway, this is far **not** your initial question :)

Comment: it worked, I found the way to clear cookies, thanks man

Comment: I know . I'm happy I could help you.